# Can I add variable to select tag ? $("#sometag")

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to remove the Tag (  card11, card3, card29....cardX )

```
var card_id = 11 ; 
$("#card"+card_id).remove();      


// ( maybe the card_id is 13, 19, 22 or 27...so it must be a variable)
```

I had test this way

```
  $("#card"+"11").remove();
```

It works, but I hope it was a variable.

Comment: **Yes**, you can use variables & concat it in selector using `+` operator. So, that should work. If you want to remove all the elements whose ID starts as `card`, `$('[id^="card"]').remove();`

Comment: `$("#card"+card_id).remove();` should work. what is the issue with this?

Comment: I hope all the `cards` share same `css class` . You can use `class selector`  also.  `$('.cardclass').remove();`

Comment: Fiddle for you: https://jsfiddle.net/remix1201/b75odru0/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup, that should work just fine. If you have an array of ID's to remove, you could just loop through them too.

```js
var cardIDs = [1, 2, 3];

for(var i = 0; i < cardIDs.length; i++) {
  $('#card'+cardIDs[i]).remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="card1">Card 1</span>
<span id="card2">Card 2</span>
<span id="card3">Card 3</span>
```